# application.html.haml Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, sign

**No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out.user"**

```
!!!
 %html
  %head
  %title MyBascamp1
%meta{:content => "width=device-width,initial-scale=1", :name => "viewport"}/
= csrf_meta_tags
= csp_meta_tag
= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: 'all', "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"
```

This is body section(more details ;)

```
%body
- if user_signed_in?
  = link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
= yield
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two different problems. There were some missing configuration steps on your project and you need to use `data-turbo-method` instead of method. Update the `link_to` with the following.

```
= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, 'data-turbo-method': :delete
```

**Configuration steps**

Add `rails-ujs` to the `application.html.haml` head.

```
= javascript_include_tag "rails-ujs"
```

Add the precompile of `rails-ujs` to `app/config/initializers/asserts.rb`

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( rails-ujs.js )
```

Comment: It's not working

Comment: @AzizbekNusratilloyev Is it the same error?

Comment: Yes, nothing happened

Comment: @AzizbekNusratilloyev Can you please provide more context?

Comment: I push all files in Git-hub                  https://github.com/SpelAzik/My_basecamp_1.git

Comment: @AzizbekNusratilloyev I updated my answer you were missing some configuration steps. Follow my instructions restart the server and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for helping all things working